# Filter collection with select dropdown in Rails with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, ransack

I am new to Ransack and I am pretty confused to get to the result I want. If anybody can shed a light I'll be grateful.
I am trying to create a filter by "City" for the ship_projects collection in the view statistics/index and I am using Ransack.

The models `ShipProjects` and `Cities` are far apart with many relations.

**ship_projects** < has_many **ship_groups** < has_many **shipments** > belongs_to **people**

**people** < has_many **postal_addresses** > belongs_to **cities**

**Models**

```
class ShipProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ship_groups
  has_many :shipments, through: :ship_groups

class ShipGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ship_project
  has_many :shipments

class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :ship_group

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postal_addresses
  has_many :cities, through: :postal_addresses

class PostalAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :city

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postal_addresses
```

**Statistics Controller**

```
  def index
    @q = ShipProject.ransack(params[:q])
    @ship_projects = @q.result.includes(:people, :cities)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx { render xlsx: 'index', filename: 'reporte_envios.xlsx' }
    end
  end
```

**statistics/index.html.erb**

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <div class='form-inline form-group'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <%= f.label :city_id_eq, "City" %><br/>
        <%= f.select :city_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all.order(:name), :id, :name, @q.city_id_eq), { }, {class: 'form-control'} %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= f.submit "Filter", class: 'btn btn-info btn-block' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the console I'am getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/statistics" for ::1 at 2015-08-12 17:51:39 -0500
Processing by StatisticsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 8  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered statistics/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `city_id_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007fc481bf3478>:
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `city_id` column in `ShipProject` db table. Then add the suitable relations:

```
ShipProject
  belongs_to :city

City
  has_many :ship_projects
```

Then of course you need a way to save the `city_id` whenever you create a `ShipProject`.